# firebase .childRemoved does not call on the second level but calls on higher levels

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

every time i call

`let jbref = Database.database().reference().child("someString")
 jbref.observe(.childRemoved) { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
        }`

it doesn't respond to any child removed at this path but it responds for any other path and i don't know why it keeps doing this. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i am not getting no error it just doesn't call the .childRemove closure only at this level. for example if i remove a child of the very top root, it calls the closure. but if try remove a child of the root's child like the code in my question, it doesn't call the closure